# OneToOne relation with sonata_type_admin : field not linked to an admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I installed the Sonata Admin bundle for manage an online library. I just wanted to link an `image` to an `author`.

The mapping is correct :
[Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
[Database] OK - The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.

This is the field of my `author` entity :

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=255)
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Project\BackendBundle\Entity\Image", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $image;
```

I create an Admin class for each entity :

- ImageAdmin.php works correctly. When I add a new image, the database is updated and the image is uploaded.
- Then I create the AuthorAdmin thanks to the documentation (http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-admin).

AuthorAdmin.php

```
class AuthorAdmin extends Admin
{
    // Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Author name'))
            ->add('image', 'sonata_type_admin')
        ;
    }

    // Fields to be shown on filter forms
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('name')
        ;
    }

    // Fields to be shown on lists
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('name')
        ;
    }
}
```

But i always have this message :

> The current field `image` is not linked to an admin. Please create one
>   for the target entity : ``

The admins are set in the admin.yml :

```
services:
    sonata.admin.author:
        class: Project\BackendBundle\Admin\AuthorAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Content", label: "Author" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - Project\BackendBundle\Entity\Author
            - ~

    sonata.admin.image:
        class: Project\BackendBundle\Admin\ImageAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Content", label: "Image" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - Project\BackendBundle\Entity\Image
            - 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD'
```

I followed all the documentation but now I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mapping is not correct. There should not be such line.

```
@ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=255)
```

`@ORM\Column` overrides `@ORM\OneToOne` and Doctrine sees this field as simple field - not as association.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-onetoone

Comment: I didn't know this behavior about @ORM\Column. Thanks a lot for enlightening this detail. It works perfectly now. I just want to understand how this annotation prevents Sonata Admin Bundle to fetch the Image Admin class. I mean, when the bundle starts generating the form, it uses Doctrine to check an existing relation ?

Comment: I think Sonata looks at Doctrine's `ClassMetadataInfo::associationMappings['image']['targetEntity']` value. But there is no such association as `@ORM\Column` overlaps `@ORM\OneToOne` (this is related with `AnnotationDriver` inner behavior).

Comment: Ok so the simple presence of the @ORM\Column prevents the ClassMetadataInfo to fetch of the targetentity of the image field. I'll try to inspect the code of the bundle. Thanks a lot for having sharing your point of view.